# What are exactly git commands executed while clicking Repository/Compress Database in GUI ($git gui)

Tags: git, user-interface, compression

I would like to know what are exactly git commands executed while clicking Repository/Compress Database in GUI ($git gui)
Is it possible for somebody to write it what is executed in this menu option?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the [sources](https://repo.or.cz/w/git-gui.git/), here's what it does :

```
${NS}::button $w.buttons.gc -text [mc "Compress Database"] \
  34                 -default normal \
  35                 -command "destroy $w;do_gc"

// < snip >

proc do_gc {} {
  72         set w [console::new {gc} [mc "Compressing the object database"]]
  73         console::chain $w {
  74                 {exec git pack-refs --prune}
  75                 {exec git reflog expire --all}
  76                 {exec git repack -a -d -l}
  77                 {exec git rerere gc}
```

So the interesting part (git commands) is :

```
git pack-refs --prune
git reflog expire --all
git repack -a -d -l
git rerere gc
```

Docs here :
[git pack-refs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs)
[git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)
[git repack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack)
[git rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere)

Comment: Thanks. I will able to check it tomorrow and I hope this will result in mark this answer as a Green Check. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: It seems odd to run those four commands with those arguments, rather than just one `git gc` (which does more than those four, but is the more user-ish variety). But `git gui` is ancient and poorly maintained, so who knows...

Comment: @torek Yeah, I've refrained from knee-jerking answer "it does git gc under the hood", because I thought "maybe not" and went to search in sources, and I've been quite surprised.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there is a way to trace commands as they are run, you may try activating one of [`git`'s tracing env variables](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITTRACEcode) when launching `git gui` :

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git gui
```

---

The code, however, is actually accessible : look at the [`git-gui/git-gui.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/69a9c10c95e28df457e33b3c7400b16caf2e2962/git-gui/git-gui.sh) file in `git`'s repo.

- searching for `Compress database` leads to [that file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/69a9c10c95e28df457e33b3c7400b16caf2e2962/git-gui/git-gui.sh#L2810),
- searching for `do_gc` to [that function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/69a9c10c95e28df457e33b3c7400b16caf2e2962/git-gui/lib/database.tcl#L71) :

```
proc do_gc {} {
    set w [console::new {gc} [mc "Compressing the object database"]]
    console::chain $w {
        {exec git pack-refs --prune}
        {exec git reflog expire --all}
        {exec git repack -a -d -l}
        {exec git rerere gc}
    }
}
```

(*note* : links to code from the state of [branch `master` on 2021-12-19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69a9c10c95e28df457e33b3c7400b16caf2e2962))

Answer (score 1):

```
strace -qqv -f -e execve -e signal=\!all git gui
```

will show you exactly what `git gui` and all its children exec, a little cleanup (in vim it's `:set nowrap|g/execve(/.,/ = 0$/j`) leaves me looking at

```
[jthill@gadabout tmp.eEjBFrhhXH]$ strace -qqvfeexecve -e signal='!all' git gui
execve("/home/jthill/bin/git", ["git", "gui"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/home/jthill/.co"..., "LESS=FRX", "XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedeskto"...,
[pid 278871] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-gui", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"...], ["CFLAGS=-march=native -pipe -Os ", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "CXXFLAGS=-march=native -pipe -Os"..., "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:pa"..., 
[pid 278871] execve("/usr/bin/wish", ["wish", "/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/home/jthill/.co"..., "LESS
[pid 278872] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--version"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/home/jt
[pid 278873] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--exec-path"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/home/
[pid 278874] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-rev-parse", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--git-dir"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIR
[pid 278875] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-rev-parse", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--show-prefix"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG
[pid 278876] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-config", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--null", "--list"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG
[pid 278877] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-rev-parse", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--show-toplevel"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONF
[pid 278878] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-rev-parse", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--is-bare-repository"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG
[pid 278879] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--html-path"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/home/
[pid 278880] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/aspell", ["aspell", "--mode=none", "--encoding=utf-8", "pipe"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/hom
[pid 278882] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-rev-parse", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--verify", "HEAD"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CON
[pid 278883] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-update-index", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "-q", "--unmerged", "--ignore-missing", "--refresh"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=503316
[pid 278892] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-diff-index", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--cached", "--ignore-submodules=dirty", "-z", "da4cafc2a0046d629716cac96875e1aa"...], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/g
[pid 278893] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-diff-files", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "-z"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/hom
[pid 278894] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-ls-files", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--others", "-z", "--exclude-standard"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=t
[pid 278905] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-pack-refs", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "--prune"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=
[pid 278906] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-reflog", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "expire", "--all"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_
[pid 278914] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-rerere", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "gc"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/home/jt
[pid 278920] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-config", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "gui.wmstate", "normal"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=truecolor", "XDG_C
[pid 278921] execve("/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/git-config", ["/home/jthill/libexec/git-core/gi"..., "gui.geometry", "923x419+997+602 191 190"], ["SHELL=/bin/bash", "SESSION_MANAGER=local/gadabout:@"..., "WINDOWID=50331678", "COLORTERM=
[jthill@gadabout tmp.eEjBFrhhXH]$
```